# How to make dynamic data table with headers spanning multiple rows using JSF and values from database?

Tags: jsf, datatable

I want a data table to be dynamically made from the values from the database using JSF.

The table should look like.

```
|Header
|           |  col2    | col2    |  col2     |
| Minor     |  --------------------------------
|           |   col2   |   col3  |    col4   |
```

Comment: In RichFaces there is `<rich:column rowspan="2">`, similar in Primefaces `<p:column rowspan="#{list.sublist.someSizeExpression}">`

Comment: Can you please give a example on it i will use primefaces

Comment: [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml)

Comment: Here the headers are only spanned , but i want the values the problen that the values wont be constant for a single cell there may be two three or many sub rows and that is not fixed i want that kind of table.

Comment: You can use table and subtable for that

Comment: This is the first time i m trying this can you please send me one example sorry bothering you

Comment: [subtable example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml)

Comment: <c:forEach var="i" items="#{test.clusterfull}" >
                <tr>
                 <c:forEach var="j" items="#{test.clustername}" >
      <td>#{j[0]}</td>
         </c:forEach>
         <td>#{i[0]}</td>
         <td>#{i[1]}</td>
       </tr>
      
            </c:forEach>

Comment: This approach is correct for one time shot, but not for dynamic table build/refresh. Subtable should be used for real dynamic table with AJAX features.

Comment: But this is also not working beacuse Where the group name is single and it has sub groups in name and count.
I want the values to be fetched from database instead of being hardcoded in the jsf page the problem that is happening is I cannot get the data table fetched from the database to row span the group column and if I do the loops are getting nested.
Group will be only one but the name and count for a group may be n depending on values from database. 
I WANT THE SUBGROUP ON ROWS BUT IT IS NOT WORKING

Comment: You can insert table in table cell. For inner table you can use `p:dataGrid` or `ui:repeat`.